# Get properties of T

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

I want to create some `class<T>`, and then in one of it's method where T object ("model") passed I need to access `model.Property1` and `model.Property2`

What expression I need to pass into class constructor to access properties?

I was thinking of something like:

```
public MyClass(Expression<Func<T, object>> prop1, Expression<Func<T, object>> prop2)
```

But here I found only how to get properties name (which I need also) using MemberInfo:

```
void MyMethod(T model, ...)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop1.Member.Name)
}
```

How can I access properties itself?
Something like `prop1.Invoke(model)` ?

Comment: If you weant to access the properties value you have to get the Getter-/Setter-method that applies to that property as properties are only shortcuts for methods. There is no way to get/set the value via the property itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, either use Generics (best) or reflection (slower, less save)

```
object p1 = model.GetType().GetProperty("Property1").GetValue(model)
```

you could also abuse dynamic(dirty!), since it basicly does the same as reflection

```
dynamic d = model; 
object p1 = d.Property1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a generic class for the object using something like this:

```
class MyClass<T, U>
    where T : class
    where U : struct
{ }
```

You can create an interface giving you access to the properties:

```
class IModel{
    public int id {get; set;}
}
class MyClass<T, U>
    where T : IModel
    where U : struct
{ }
```

Then when you reference T in the code you can access id from the Model like so:

```
    class MyClass<T, U>
        where T : IModel
        where U : struct
    { 
        public void DoStuff(T myModel){
            int a = myModel.id;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Expressions cannot be executed directly. In order to do that, you need to turn passed `Expression<Func<..>>` to `Func<..>`, which is achieved by [Compile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this

```
void MyMethod(T model, ...)
{
    var prop1Value1 = prop1.Compile()(model);
}
```

For performance reasons you may consider compiling the expressions inside the class constructor and storing the resulting delegates in a class fields.

Also, if all you need is to be able to get values, you may consider changing the costructor signature to accept `Func<..>`s instead

```
public MyClass(Func<T, object> prop1, Func<T, object> prop2)
```